# Sending commands to Arduino with Bluetooth in Android app gives exception (message: invalid UUID)

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, uuid

I'll to send commands to an Arduino by using Bluetooth. The application I've made is an Android app. The problem on code below, is that the last line gives this exception:

> **`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:** Invalid UUID: 86663102937730

Here is the code:

```
private void sendViaBluetooth() {

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    else {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (devices.size() != 0) {

            for (BluetoothDevice device : devices){

                if (device.getName().equals("HC-06")){
                    sendDataToPairedDevice(edtText.getText().toString(), device);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void sendDataToPairedDevice(String message ,BluetoothDevice device) {

    byte[] toSend = message.getBytes();
    try {
        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();

        UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString(uuid); // <-- Gives IllegalArgumentException
        BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
        OutputStream mmOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        mmOutStream.write(toSend); // <-- gives NullPointerException (see update below)
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("", "Exception during write", e);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("", ex.toString());
    }
}
```

I've also added this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

---

**Update:**

By an answer of @neferpitou, I've update this code:

```
UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString(uuid);
```

to this:

```
UUID applicationUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
```

It works but now my code gives now a `NullPointerException` on the line with the comment. The variable `toSend` is not null so you can see on image below.

[image]

Comment: The alleged UUID (86X63X029X77X0) looks invalid to me.  I'm not sure what the "_blinded numbers_" are all about; but from a UUID perspective, this SO question does not present a valid UUID.  Perhaps http://www.mahonri.info/cgi/uuid.cgi would be helpful to validate specific UUIDs?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer: I've update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it! :) Here is my code

```
private void sendDataToPairedDevice(String message ,BluetoothDevice device) {

    try {
        myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice dispositivo = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());
        btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
        BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
        btSocket.connect();

        btSocket.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("", "Exception during write", e);
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A valid UUID looks like this `aae51ae6-c8c5-4805-9637-2722b683ca93`.

Try replacing your code with:

```
UUID applicationUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
```

**Update:**

The `.write()` can only handle 1 byte of data, but there is an easier way to write `Strings` in `OutputStream`. Use `BufferedWriter`:

Replace

```
mmOutStream.write(toSend);
```

with

```
BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mmOutStream,"UTF-8"));
                buffWriter.write(message);
                buffWriter.flush();
```

And lastly create a finally block in your `try-catch` and close your `buffWriter` e.g. `buffWriter.close();`

Comment: It gives me now a `NullReferenceException` on this line: `mmOutStream.write(toSend); `